# Filter array in javascript removing items when not found in case of multiple filter values

Tags: javascript

Consider there are multiple filter values to be filtered in a list. In the 1st iteration, if the 1st filter value is not matching any items in the list, all the items are getting deleted and I would have no elements to filter the list using the 2nd filter value.

I am trying to filter my array in javascript with the below code. I have an admin list and I want to filter the admins based on the event IDs. The below code is failing if I have 2 event IDs to be filtered using the list.

```
if(aEventIds.length > 0) {
        aEventIds.forEach(function(eventId) {
          aAdminList = aAdminList.filter(function(item) {
            searchedOrFiltered = true;
            return (item.event_ids.includes(parseInt(eventId)));
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: please share input array and expected ouput

Comment: Data transformation questions should always include the input and expected output of the transformation process. Please edit your question to include both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array.prototype.filter` callback function should return a Boolean indicating whether to keep the current iteration's value. All you need to do is invert your logic so that your filter is considering each of your ids rather than each of your ids being used to performing an individual filtering.

So if this is an OR operations on the IDs, then this:

```js
let aAdminList = [{event_ids: [1, 5, 8]},{event_ids: [3, 6, 9]},{event_ids: [2, 4, 8]}];
let aEventIds = [5, 8];

let output = aAdminList.filter(item => {
  searchedOrFiltered = true;
  let result = [];
  aEventIds.forEach(eventId => {
    result.push(item.event_ids.includes(parseInt(eventId)));
  });
  // OR OP
  return result.includes(true);
});

console.log(output);
```

Otherwise, if this is an AND operation on the IDs then this:

```js
let aAdminList = [{event_ids: [1, 5, 8]},{event_ids: [3, 6, 9]},{event_ids: [2, 4, 8]}];
let aEventIds = [5, 8];

let output = aAdminList.filter(item => {
  searchedOrFiltered = true;
  let result = [];
  aEventIds.forEach(eventId => {
    result.push(item.event_ids.includes(parseInt(eventId)));
  });
  // AND OP
  return result.every(i=>i===true);
});

console.log(output);
```